# image flatten pixel list

Tags: python, image, blender

I want to create a small python script that exports some data as image file from inside blenders python api.

I found a good tutorial, but one line is freaking me out:

```
# flatten list
pixels = [chan for px in pixels for chan in px]
```

`pixels` is an array of floats with the size of `4*width*height` (rgba-channels)

This line is after filling the array with values and before exporting the image. What does it do? Why do i need to "flatten" my pixel list? What does that even mean?

---

I don't know if important (because I'm relatively new to python), but the array was filled inside a double for loop (for x and y) by this line: `pixels[(y * size[0]) + x] = [r, g, b, a]`

Comment: Flattening the list simply converts the list from a multi-dimensional array, to a flat list (e.g. a byte stream). As to why this is needed - we will probably  need more context.

Answer (score 1):

Since we don't know what the rest of the program does, so we can't tell for sure why you need to flatten the list.  It's often just a bandwidth issue: your protocol can take only one intensity value at a time, so they have to come in a linear stream.

What you have is a list of lists, something like this:

```
[ [r1, g1, b1, a1],
  [r2, g2, b2, a2],
  ...
]
```

*Flatten* means to convert this to a list with the elements in the same order, but only one layer deep:

```
[r1, g1, b1, a1, r2, g2, b2, a2, ...]
```

The list comprehension that's freaking you out is a shorthand to do that for a list of lists.  Read this from the outside in.  I suspect that the first item in that list comprehension should be **px**, not **chan**.

```
temp = []
for chan in px:
    for px in pixels:
        temp += px
pixels = temp
```

Does that help?

Comment: ah thank you! I didn't know i was handling a list of lists... that makes sense. I now just changed the way the list got filled, so no flatting is needed anymore.